# JPA @ManyToOne @JoinFormula throwing ClassCastException

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to model a many-to-one bi-directional association using JPA. The join uses a formula. I've tried it a couple of ways, as shown below. Once with just JoinFormula and another with JoinColumnsOrFormulas.

```
public class JobOperation
{
  private Operation                 operation;

  @ManyToOne
  //  @JoinFormula("CASE WHEN attribute7 IS NULL OR TO_NUMBER(attribute7) = 0 THEN standard_operation_id ELSE TO_NUMBER(attribute7) END")
  @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(
  {
    @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(//
        value = "(CASE WHEN this_.attribute7 IS NULL OR TO_NUMBER(this_.attribute7) = 0 THEN this_.standard_operation_id ELSE TO_NUMBER(this_.attribute7) END)", // 
        referencedColumnName = "standard_operation_id"))
  })
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  public Operation getOperation()
  {
    return this.operation;
  }
}
```

I originally was using Hibernate 4.3.9 and then tried with Hibernate 5.1.0. Both throw the same exception:

```
15:55:21,408 DEBUG [org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder] Retrieving property com.icumed.ifactory3.dto.wip.JobOperation.operation
15:55:21,409 DEBUG [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] Unable to build entity manager factory
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:584)
```

Nothing in Hibernate's TableBinder class refers to a formula. Does Hibernate just not support this or am I using the wrong annotations, or is there something else going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause of the problem seems to be on the other side of the association. I originally had this

```
public class Operation extends AbstractOperation
{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="operation")
  public Set<JobOperation> getJobOperations()
  {
    return this.jobOperations;
  }
}
```

and when I changed it to the following, it worked.

```
public class Operation extends AbstractOperation
{
  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name="STANDARD_OPERATION_ID")
  public Set<JobOperation> getJobOperations()
  {
    return this.jobOperations;
  }
}
```